# Make classes work individually

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two paragraphs and I want to be able to show more details when the “more info” button is pressed. The code seems to work well. However, when you click on “more info” both top and bottom paragraphs collapse. I want to be able to make them collapse individually.

How can I accomplish that?

```js
function infobtn() {
  var s = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].style.display === "block") {
      s[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      s[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#paragraph {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5% 20% 5% 0%;
  padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#paragraph p {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0% 1% 5% 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

#paragraph .info {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#paragraph h4 {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
  margin: -4% 0% 0% 0%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#paragraph2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
  padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#paragraph2 p {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.5);
  width: 99%;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0% 1% 5% 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

#paragraph2 .info {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#paragraph2 h4 {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
  margin: -4% 0% 0% 0%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="paragraph">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et,
    tincidunt tortor. Sed sem lectus, suscipit at sollicitudin eget, euismod faucibus ex. Nam dignissim, est sit amet porttitor consectetur, tortor orci placerat augue, varius volutpat sem ante eget velit. Sed eget quam at nulla convallis pulvinar id
    non eros. Pellentesque venenatis lacus at dolor varius, molestie imperdiet ex pretium. Vestibulum scelerisque quis mauris quis posuere. Duis vitae enim non mauris malesuada dictum. Morbi suscipit aliquet leo a maximus. Nunc faucibus ut urna nec rhoncus.
    Proin semper ultricies rhoncus. Nulla efficitur rhoncus sollicitudin. Phasellus ac leo mi. Phasellus odio nulla, posuere ut ullamcorper quis, suscipit a erat. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis ipsum, pretium mollis massa laoreet ut. </p>
  <h4 onclick="infobtn()"> More info</h4>
  <div class="info">
    <h1> More info...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="paragraph2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et,
    tincidunt tortor. Sed sem lectus, suscipit at sollicitudin eget, euismod faucibus ex. Nam dignissim, est sit amet porttitor consectetur, tortor orci placerat augue, varius volutpat sem ante eget velit. Sed eget quam at nulla convallis pulvinar id
    non eros. Pellentesque venenatis lacus at dolor varius, molestie imperdiet ex pretium. Vestibulum scelerisque quis mauris quis posuere. Duis vitae enim non mauris malesuada dictum. Morbi suscipit aliquet leo a maximus. Nunc faucibus ut urna nec rhoncus.
    Proin semper ultricies rhoncus. Nulla efficitur rhoncus sollicitudin. Phasellus ac leo mi. Phasellus odio nulla, posuere ut ullamcorper quis, suscipit a erat. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis ipsum, pretium mollis massa laoreet ut. </p>
  <h4 onclick="infobtn()"> More info</h4>
  <div class="info">
    <h1> More info...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could add a parameter to `function infobtn()` that excepts an id or unique class and use that to select the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More effective solution is to use more CSS than JS

Click on button to toggle the class and show/hide the info block with CSS sibling selector:

```js
function showMore(el){
  el.classList.toggle('on');
}
```

```css
.more-content {
  display: none;
}

.more.on ~ .more-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="paragraph1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <button class="more" onclick="showMore(this)">more</button>
  <p class="more-content">inventore fugiat aliquid non. Accusantium saepe suscipit, pariatur reprehenderit odio autem velit? Qui voluptate molestias cupiditate totam dolorum architecto inventore! Ad ullam et facilis excepturi</p>
</div>

<div id="paragraph2">
  <p>Qui voluptate molestias cupiditate totam</p>
  <button class="more" onclick="showMore(this)">more</button>
  <p class="more-content">voluptates dolorum placeat eius molestias asperiores iure, sequi laudantium corporis iusto obcaecati perferendis doloribus dolorem odio. Minima, incidunt magnam expedita ratione cumque autem?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to parameterize your infobtn function. In this way you can target the info sections individually. This would also mean that you need a different class name to differentiate the two sections.

```js
function infobtn(className){
  var s= document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if(s[i].style.display==="block") {
      s[i].style.display="none";
    } else{
      s[i].style.display="block";
    } 
  } 
}
```

```css
#paragraph{ float:left; width:50%; height:auto; margin:5% 20% 5% 0%; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%;}

#paragraph p{background:rgba(200,200,200,0.5); width:98%; height:auto;  color:black; padding:1% 1% 1% 1%; float:left; overflow:hidden; margin:0% 1% 5% 0%;   text-align:center;} 

#paragraph .info{width:100%; height:auto; display:none; float:left; overflow:hidden; transition:0.5s ease-in-out; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; }

#paragraph h4{color:white; background:rgba(50,50,50,1); width:100%; height:auto; text-align:center;  padding:1% 0% 1% 0%; margin:-4% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; border-radius:5px;}

#paragraph2{ float:left; width:50%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%;}

#paragraph2 p{background:rgba(200,200,255,0.5); width:99%; height:auto;  color:black; padding:1% 1% 1% 1%; float:left; overflow:hidden; margin:0% 1% 5% 0%;   text-align:center;} 

#paragraph2 .info{width:100%; height:auto; display:none; float:left; overflow:hidden; transition:0.5s ease-in-out; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; }

#paragraph2 h4{color:white; background:rgba(50,50,50,1); width:100%; height:auto; text-align:center;  padding:1% 0% 1% 0%; margin:-4% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; border-radius:5px;}
```

```html
<div id="paragraph">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus 
a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae 
neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et, tincidunt tortor. Sed sem lectus, suscipit at sollicitudin eget, euismod faucibus ex. Nam dignissim, est sit amet porttitor consectetur, tortor orci placerat augue, varius volutpat sem ante eget velit. Sed eget quam at nulla convallis pulvinar id non eros. Pellentesque venenatis lacus at dolor varius, molestie imperdiet ex pretium. Vestibulum scelerisque quis mauris quis posuere. Duis vitae enim non mauris malesuada dictum. Morbi suscipit aliquet leo a maximus. Nunc faucibus ut urna nec rhoncus. Proin semper ultricies rhoncus. Nulla efficitur rhoncus sollicitudin. Phasellus ac leo mi. Phasellus odio nulla, posuere ut ullamcorper quis, suscipit a erat. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis ipsum, pretium mollis massa laoreet ut. </p>
<h4 onclick="infobtn('target-1')"> More info</h4>

<div class="info target-1"><h1> More info...</h1>
</div>
</div>


<div id="paragraph2">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et, tincidunt tortor. Sed sem lectus, suscipit at sollicitudin eget, euismod faucibus ex. Nam dignissim, est sit amet porttitor consectetur, tortor orci placerat augue, varius volutpat sem ante eget velit. Sed eget quam at nulla convallis pulvinar id non eros. Pellentesque venenatis lacus at dolor varius, molestie imperdiet ex pretium. Vestibulum scelerisque quis mauris quis posuere. Duis vitae enim non mauris malesuada dictum. Morbi suscipit aliquet leo a maximus. Nunc faucibus ut urna nec rhoncus. Proin semper ultricies rhoncus. Nulla efficitur rhoncus sollicitudin. Phasellus ac leo mi. Phasellus odio nulla, posuere ut ullamcorper quis, suscipit a erat. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis ipsum, pretium mollis massa laoreet ut. </p>
<h4 onclick="infobtn('target-2')"> More info</h4>

<div class="info target-2"><h1> More info...</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he still wants the `.info` class for styling purposes (notice your snippet has the second one open by default because it doesn't have the `display: none;` from the `.info` class), so since you want a unique selector you could just uses ids instead

Comment: Good point, thank you. Edited my answer to preserve the .info style on both sections.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inlining your js code i'd suggest to add the event and this keywords, like in:

```
<h4 onclick="infobtn(event, this)"> More info</h4>
```

In order to get the current style you need to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) for the [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) and [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) because:

> The window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object that reports
>   the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active
>   stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may
>   contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs
>   provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

```js
function infobtn(evt, ele){
    ele.previousElementSibling.style.display = (getComputedStyle(ele.previousElementSibling)['display'] === "block") ? 'none' : 'block';
    ele.nextElementSibling.style.display = (ele.previousElementSibling.style.display === "block") ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
#paragraph{ float:left; width:50%; height:auto; margin:5% 20% 5% 0%; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%;}

#paragraph p{background:rgba(200,200,200,0.5); width:98%; height:auto;  color:black; padding:1% 1% 1% 1%; float:left; overflow:hidden; margin:0% 1% 5% 0%;   text-align:center;}

#paragraph .info{width:100%; height:auto; display:none; float:left; overflow:hidden; transition:0.5s ease-in-out; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; }

#paragraph h4{color:white; background:rgba(50,50,50,1); width:100%; height:auto; text-align:center;  padding:1% 0% 1% 0%; margin:-4% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; border-radius:5px;}

#paragraph2{ float:left; width:50%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%;}

#paragraph2 p{background:rgba(200,200,255,0.5); width:99%; height:auto;  color:black; padding:1% 1% 1% 1%; float:left; overflow:hidden; margin:0% 1% 5% 0%;   text-align:center;}

#paragraph2 .info{width:100%; height:auto; display:none; float:left; overflow:hidden; transition:0.5s ease-in-out; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; }

#paragraph2 h4{color:white; background:rgba(50,50,50,1); width:100%; height:auto; text-align:center;  padding:1% 0% 1% 0%; margin:-4% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; border-radius:5px;}
```

```html
<div id="paragraph">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus
        a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae
        neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et, tincidunt tortor. Sed sem lectus, suscipit at sollicitudin eget, euismod faucibus ex. Nam dignissim, est sit amet porttitor consectetur, tortor orci placerat augue, varius volutpat sem ante eget velit. Sed eget quam at nulla convallis pulvinar id non eros. Pellentesque venenatis lacus at dolor varius, molestie imperdiet ex pretium. Vestibulum scelerisque quis mauris quis posuere. Duis vitae enim non mauris malesuada dictum. Morbi suscipit aliquet leo a maximus. Nunc faucibus ut urna nec rhoncus. Proin semper ultricies rhoncus. Nulla efficitur rhoncus sollicitudin. Phasellus ac leo mi. Phasellus odio nulla, posuere ut ullamcorper quis, suscipit a erat. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis ipsum, pretium mollis massa laoreet ut. </p>
    <h4 onclick="infobtn(event, this)"> More info</h4>

    <div class="info"><h1> More info...</h1>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="paragraph2">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et, tincidunt tortor. Sed sem lectus, suscipit at sollicitudin eget, euismod faucibus ex. Nam dignissim, est sit amet porttitor consectetur, tortor orci placerat augue, varius volutpat sem ante eget velit. Sed eget quam at nulla convallis pulvinar id non eros. Pellentesque venenatis lacus at dolor varius, molestie imperdiet ex pretium. Vestibulum scelerisque quis mauris quis posuere. Duis vitae enim non mauris malesuada dictum. Morbi suscipit aliquet leo a maximus. Nunc faucibus ut urna nec rhoncus. Proin semper ultricies rhoncus. Nulla efficitur rhoncus sollicitudin. Phasellus ac leo mi. Phasellus odio nulla, posuere ut ullamcorper quis, suscipit a erat. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis ipsum, pretium mollis massa laoreet ut. </p>
    <h4 onclick="infobtn(event, this)"> More info</h4>

    <div class="info"><h1> More info...</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying all the elements of that type, you can set up the click handlers to modify elements relative to the particular one that was clicked.  You can also generate these click handlers from within code instead of needing to embed them as attributes in the HTML.

More detailed explanation in comments below:

```js
// Step through each of the h4 elements:
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('h4')).forEach(function(el) {
  // bind a click handler to this h4 element:
  el.onclick = function() {
    // find the element we want to show or hide, which follows the h4:
    var info = el.nextElementSibling;
    // toggle its display:
    info.style.display = (info.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block")
  }
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="paragraph">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus.</p>
  <h4> More info</h4>
  <div class="info">
    <h1> More info...</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="paragraph2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque nisl, gravida vitae tellus a, commodo mattis risus. Pellentesque nec libero maximus, imperdiet justo tincidunt, placerat risus. Cras vitae neque tincidunt, sagittis turpis et</p>
  <h4> More info</h4>
  <div class="info">
    <h1> More info...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! 
It's amazing how this issue can be solved in so many ways.
Thank you everyone! 
I'm thankful that I can learn from all of you!